# Are vertx-web route handlers a singleton or does it instantiate a new one every time?

Tags: java, multithreading, vert.x

I am new to Java and vertx. In creating a vertx-web PoC, I chose instance properties on my handlers as an easy way to share data in a futures chain because of callbacks. Looking at my code someone asked if my implementation was multi-threaded. I started reading more docs and came across event-loop/worker threads and standard/worker/multi-thread verticles. This then mutated into wondering about concurrent calls.

**In providing a handler to Route.handler() does a new TestHandler get instantiated for every request or does handler create a singleton on the Route and TestHandler bar shared for concurrent requests?**

If it is a singleton. How could i handle concurrency? More instances on the vertx deployment? Stateless Handler classes?

Java examples and articles seem to use demonstrate things in a very simple context and leaves any implementation to be coupled with a working knowledge of advanced concepts. This has been making learning Java very difficult. Any help/tips/advice for a new Java dev would be much appreciated.

*Application.java*

```
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    vertx.deployVerticle("com.foo.testServer");
  }
}
```

*TestServer.java*

```
public class TestServer extends AbstractVerticle {
  @Override
  public void start() {
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    router.post("/test").handler(new TestHandler());

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router).listen(8000);
  }
}
```

*TestHandler.java*

```
public class TestHandler implements Handler<RoutingContext> {
  private String bar;

  // ... other future methods

  public void handle(@NotNull RoutingContext ctx) {
    bar = ctx.getBodyAsJson().getString("bar");

    // ... future method calls

    ctx.response().setStatusCode(200).end(bar);
  }
}
```

Comment: First, get a copy of *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz.  Best book on multi threading and will basically explain everything for you.

Comment: I'm looking at the docs for vert.x now but it looks pretty extensive, I may not be able to find anything.  Basically that's the answer: read the docs.  If the docs don't explain anything about multi threading a library, you have to assume you can't.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Vert.x is to be able to handle a lot of concurrent requests with very few threads, using non-blocking APIs.

Indeed, when you deploy a verticle, an event loop is assigned to the instance and a single thread will handle the events.
This is by design and it relieves the developer from thinking about complex multi-threading issues.

Then of course modern hardware often provides multiple cores. In this case, you can deploy multiple instances of your verticle. You will still benefit from the single-threaded development model and also take advantage of all the CPU cores.

More on this in the [Reactor and Multi-Reactor](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_reactor_and_multi_reactor) section of the Vert.x core docs.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in vert.x instances of `Handler`, `Promise` and `Future` are singletons and are instantiated on once-per-verticle-instance basis.

As soon as they are supposed to be thread-safe (pure functional, no shared-state), they can be used in multi-threaded environments by default.